# Navigated the same page again after pop

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router

I used go_router and sometimes when do pop opened same bottom sheet again, but I nowhere do push in that bottom sheet again. I notice that router stack(router.routerDelegate.currentConfiguration.matches) don't changed after pop because of that again showed bottom sheet so for what it can be and why router don't updated?